# Split string by commas then Store in array val in Play! + Scala

Tags: html, scala, playframework, split, playframework-2.0

I am passing a List

```
errors.add(new ValidationError("Employee " + strId, "error.range," + strName +","+ intRange));
```

that will build a string

```
"Employee1","error.format,FIRST NAME,20
```

I want to split the message string with "," and store it in a array variable in scala template or twirl in view. I'm not really good at scala code i don't know how to store a variable in scala template nor know the syntax in splitting a string. Is there a code that can do this task in scala template?. Thank you.

```
<div id = "msg-menu" class = "msg-menu">
    @for((key, value) <- appModel.errors) {
        <div class="error-msg">
          <p>@key :
             @for(err <- value) {
                @for(error <- err.message.split(",")) {
                    @Messages(error)
                }
             }
          </p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

What i did was use a for loop to do it but it is not what i needed. i need to declare all the string in an array and use them as parameters on the `@Messages`. like:

```
@Messages(error[0],error[1],error[2])
```

In which error0 = "error.range", error1 = "FIRST NAME" and error2 = "20". In conf/message i will build an error message with the parameters

```
error.range = Enter {0} in {1} characters or less.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are definined in twirl using `@defining`, in the following way:

```
@defining( err.message.split(",").lift ) { errors =>
  ...
}
```

The use of `lift` could be handy, as it helps with index out of bounds conditions where you might not know the exact number of elements in the array / collection. errors(2) will return `Some("20")` in your example and `None` if there isn't a value.

Replacing your innermost for loop with the above and hardcoding to exactly 3 parameters, you might then have something like

```
  @defining( errors(0).getOrElse("") ) { messageId =>
    @Message(messageId,errors(1).getOrElse(""),errors(2).getOrElse(""))
  }
```

Comment: I learned so many things about scala twirl in this answer of yours. Thanks a bunch. I used @defining a while a go buy had a problem in array size giving me errors so what i did was put an else if statement with the condition of arrayParam.size == 1 and so on. it takes so many messages declaration in the condtions. and you just made it this short. thank very much.